# How to convert a publication written in Latex to markdown?

Tags: bibliographies, pandoc, markdown

I'm trying to convert a Latex file to a markdown format with `pandoc 3.1` but the resulting markdown file doesn't generate the title nor the references properly. I'm kind of at my wits end here as nothing I do seems to have the correct output. I'm not sure how to proceed. I'll provide a minimal example below:

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{title}
\author{}
\affil{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Summary}
Sentence one \cite{gavison1980privacy, martin2017role}. \cite{westin1968privacy} sentence two.

\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

`references.bib`

```
@article{gavison1980privacy,
  title={Privacy and the Limits of Law},
  author={Gavison, Ruth},
  journal={The Yale law journal},
  volume={89},
  number={3},
  pages={421--471},
  year={1980},
  publisher={JSTOR}
}

@article{martin2017role,
  title={The role of data privacy in marketing},
  author={Martin, Kelly D and Murphy, Patrick E},
  journal={Journal of the Academy of Marketing Science},
  volume={45},
  pages={135--155},
  year={2017},
  publisher={Springer US}
}

@article{westin1968privacy,
  title={Privacy and freedom},
  author={Westin, Alan F},
  journal={Washington and Lee Law Review},
  volume={25},
  number={1},
  pages={166},
  year={1968}
}
```

I'm using the following pandoc command:
`pandoc -o output.md main.tex --bibliography=references.bib`

I've also tried adding the `apa.csl` and adding a `--csl=apa.csl` in the pandoc command. No dice.
The output is always the following with no title or references:

```
# Summary

Sentence one [@gavison1980privacy; @martin2017role]. @westin1968privacy
sentence two.
```

I'd want something like the following:

```
---
title: "titl"
author: ""
date: ""
bibliography: references.bib
csl: apa.csl
---

# Privacy Metrics

## Summary

Sentence one (Gavison, 1980; Martin & Murphy, 2017). Westin (1968) sentence two.

## References

<div id="refs" class="references">

<div id="ref-gavison1980privacy">

Gavison, R. (1980). Privacy and the Limits of Law. *The Yale law journal*, *89*(3), 421–471. https://doi.org/10.2307/795662

</div>

<div id="ref-martin2017role">

Martin, K. D., & Murphy, P. E. (2017). The role of data privacy in marketing. *Journal of the Academy of Marketing Science*, *45*, 135–155. https://doi.org/10.1007/s11747-016-0496-x

</div>

<div id="ref-westin1968privacy">

Westin, A. F. (1968). Privacy and freedom. *Washington and Lee Law Review*, *25*(1), 166.

</div>

</div>
```

Comment: What you want is *not* markdown, but a mix of markdown with HTML.

Comment: Use `--standalone` to get the title and bib information in a header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is not convert to markdown, but a mix of markdown with HTML, that is not possible with pandoc, AFAIK. What you obtain is markdowm, but not a complete (*standalone*) document, but using `-s`:

```
$ pandoc -s -t markdown -f latex main.tex
```

You will obtain this:

```
---
bibliography:
- references.bib
title: title
---

Summary
=======

Sentence one [@gavison1980privacy; @martin2017role].
[@westin1968privacy] sentence two.
```

That is a complete document.

[image: mwe]

Note that date and author are not exported because the argument is empty, whereas `\affil`, well, is an undefined command ...

Note that there are not automatic title for the bibliography using `citeproc`. You can simply add this at the end of the markdown text (e.g., `# References`, modify the template, or change a bit the header and render it with [Quarto](https://quarto.org/) (save it with extension `.qmd`):

```
---
title: "title"
bibliography: references.bib
format:
  pdf: 
    cite-method: biblatex # or natbib
biblio-style: apa # for biblatex only
---

Summary
=======

Sentence one [@gavison1980privacy; @martin2017role].
[@westin1968privacy] sentence two.
```

[image: wme2]

Comment: Thank you--it was very informative. Will accept as answer.